# Dependensy property: ошибка при повторной регистрации

Tags: wpf

В окне `WPF` регистрирую `dependency property`, при первом вызове этого окна все отлично. Закрываю окно методом `Close()` и открываю повторно валится с ошибкой 'Свойство "`Property`" уже зарегистрировано "`Window`"'. Что делаю не так? Как можно сбросить или обновить регистрацию свойства? Пока нашел решение делать из этого окна синглтон, но это крайне не удобно. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: DependencyProperty (как и RoutedEvent) следует регистрировать в инициализаторах статических полей или в статическом конструкторе.

Comment: Приведите код, из вашего описания ничего не понятно. В качестве совета, генерируйте dependency property при помощи [шортката `propdp`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702042/quickly-create-dependency-properties-in-vs), так уж точно не ошибётесь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Проблему решил регистрируя свойства таким образом

public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseSource",
                    typeof(ImageSource), typeof(SearchResultWindow),
                    new PropertyMetadata(ImagesResources.Instance.CloseInActive));

А если не указывать static readonly появляется описанная мною проблема.

Comment: @apal: ну да, так и есть. Если бы вы привели код, было бы сразу понятно.